# How to Run a DELETE query after SELECT in c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-delete

I have this code. The first code selects email from notify table and then creates a list of them, which I then I loop through and send email.

However, now I am stuck as i need to delete the notify_id i've just used from the notify table. Could someone help me with this please.

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM notify WHERE jump_id = @jump_id", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jump_id", jumpid.Text);

                    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

                    List<String> user = new List<String>(); 

                    while (rd.Read()) 
                    {
                        userAddre.Add((String)rd.GetValue(0));

                    }
    if (userAddre.Count > 0) //if exists
                    {
    //do something
    }

            using (SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM notify WHERE notify_if = ", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(????);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: have you tried getting your notify_if in your first query and passing it through to the second one?

Comment: The syntax would be the same as you have used in the `SELECT` statement above. You just need to fetch the `notify_id` also along with `email` and store in a variable and pass to the `DELETE` query.

Comment: Also, the nesting of SqlCommand `using` scopes might generate an error here.

Comment: The "correct" approach (in many databases) would be to combine the DELETE with an appropriate JOIN/WHERE clause, instead of using two statements. It will also implicitly avoid an immediate lack-of-transaction issue.

Comment: @user2864740 hi, how could I do this

Comment: @iwuhdiwuhfwuiqhf Hmm, if you want to 'do something' before the delete *and* that something can affect the DELETE, still use two separate commands (I missed that part). But you may be interested in creating a transaction ([eg see TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) over all the operations.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Your SELECT statemnt retunrs only email, You should so sth like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT email, notify_if FROM notify WHERE jump_id = @jump_id", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jump_id", jumpid.Text);

                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

                List<String> user = new List<String>(); 
                List<int> ids = new List<int>();

                while (rd.Read()) 
                {
                    userAddre.Add((String)rd.GetValue(0));
                    ids.Add((int)rd.GetValue(1))

                }
if (userAddre.Count > 0) //if exists
                {
//do something
}

        using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM notify WHERE notify_if = ", con))
        {
//Here add some elements from ids list.
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(????);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

I don't know how many rows it returns, so it's hard to give exact solution.

Please note that delete could be set in separated method with parameter of key and fired for each id from ids list.

Comment: You have to create method:

DeleteRow(int param) {
using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM notify WHERE notify_if = @id", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}

and simply start this DeleteRow method for each element if list callet ids (what I added in Your code)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

look when you are selecting the email from first query same time select or retrieve the notify_if and stored it in any variable and pass it to second query i.t to your delete query.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd =
        new SqlCommand("SELECT email, notify_if FROM notify WHERE jump_id = @jump_id", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jump_id", jumpid.Text);

            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

            List<String> user = new List<String>(); 
           // here declaration for your id
            List<int> notifyId = new List<int>();

            while (rd.Read()) 
            {
                userAddre.Add((String)rd.GetValue(0));
                notifyId.Add((int)rd.GetValue(1))

            }
            if (userAddre.Count > 0) //if exists
            {
     //do something
     }

    using (SqlCommand cmd =
        new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM notify WHERE notify_if =@id ", con))
      {
          // suming that you want delete multiple Notifyid
        for (int i = 0; i < notifyId.Count; i++) 
        {
             cmd.Parameters.Clear();//clear the parameter on each loop
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",notifyId[i]);
        }
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: it will get added into list when your select query is executed successfully

Comment: check are you getting the result from first query successfully.. from where r u getting the @jump_id value?

Comment: It won't let me build, `Error The name 'notifyId' does not exist in the current context `

Comment: @Sachu I do, but it doesn't find the notify_id before I even start building it, whatt am i doing wrong

Comment: try declaring the both <list> just before the first "using" List<String> user = new List<String>(); 
            List<int> notifyId = new List<int>(); both declare just before first Using

Comment: I am getting an error 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first' in the delete cmd

Comment: @iwuhdiwuhfwuiqhf just before second using do rd.close();

Comment: @iwuhdiwuhfwuiqhf just test my answer according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<String> user = new List<String>(); 

 List<int> notifyId = new List<int>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
           {
           try
             {
            conn.ConnectionString = "data source=servername;User ID=username;Password=oasswordn;initial catalog=database;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
            conn.Open();

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,email FROM test", conn);
          SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
        while (rd.Read()) 
           {
                        notifyId.Add(Convert.ToInt16(rd.GetValue(0)));
                        user.Add(rd.GetValue(1).ToString());

                    }
        if(user.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < user.Count; i++)
                MessageBox.Show(user[i].ToString());
            }
         rd.Close();

         cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM test WHERE id =@id ", conn);
        for (int i = 0; i < notifyId.Count; i++)
           {
               cmd.Parameters.Clear();//clear the parameter on each loop
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", notifyId[i]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
           conn.Close();
          }
              catch(Exception e1)
                {

                 }
     }
```

This code is working in my environment

Comment: @iwuhdiwuhfwuiqhf this code is working in my environment..where i have a table "Test" with two column "id" and "email"

Comment: @iwuhdiwuhfwuiqhf hope its fine now